# CSS3 Transform and Perspective

Tags: javascript, css, transform, perspective

I have an image that I'm rotating using rotateY. At the moment it rotates through 90 degrees (i.e. is edge on for the viewer) I want to reduce its opacity (using JavaScript). Thus it appears faded when it's back is to the viewer.

However, since I have a perspective set, it doesn't actually appear edge on when rotated through 90 degrees.

Is there a way to determine when the image appears edge on, without churning through the transform calculations myself?

Comment: no there is not.. post some code so some one could help you

Comment: Could you update the code in fiddle.

Comment: I asume that you know about backface-visibility, and so you want this only for IE ?

Comment: Here's the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/mfbdr905/1/

Note I'm switching color rather than opactity to make things clearer. With no perspective the color change just as the div is edge on. With perspective the div is visible as the change happens.

Can't use backface-visibility since I onlt want to fade it, not make it completely invisible.